# How to read a multispectral image?

Tags: python, tiff

I have multispectral images with the `.tif` extension. How can I read such multispectral images with Python?

Answer (score 0):

Pillow module supports "Multi-frame TIFF Images" that might be your thing.
Could you provide an example file you would like to open and, what do you expect inside?

https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/image-file-formats.html#reading-multi-frame-tiff-images

This might do the job:

```
from PIL import Image
im = Image.open("image.tif")

print(im.num_frames)
im.seek(im.tell() + 1))
```